# How to send emails using google smtp with angular 4

Tags: angular, smtp, gmail

I want to send **mails** using `google smpt` with my `angular 4 app`. I tried to send emails using [email js](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs). but I couldn't use it with my `angular 4 app`. when I try to import, it says no any modules. how can I send mails using this `existing library` or , is there any other way to send mails with `angular 4 application` using `google smpt`.

Comment: Would you be able to share the code you're using?

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do won't work. You need a nodejs server-side app for that framework.
From `emailjs` page you sent: `send emails, html and attachments (files, streams and strings) from node.js to any smtp server`.

Try this service instead https://www.emailjs.com/docs/api-reference/installation/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/dist/email.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("YOUR USER ID");
   })();
</script>
```

You need to create an account in their website and replace the "YOUR USER ID" with your personal ID of your account.

Comment: are you able to give an example of how this package would be imported into an Angular component?

Comment: you would need to add the script `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/dist/email.min.js"></script>
` in your vendors file or just place it in the <head> if you want to test it out. then in your component try onAfterViewInit() `const emailJS = window['emailjs'];` and ... probably it will work by `emailJS.init("you_personal_id");`

Comment: Thanks. I found that I had to load the emailjs into the component with import/as:

import * as emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

and then, the init function that would go into the header:
emailjs.init('<USER ID>');
I instead placed it right before the send function, so it looks like this:

someFunction(){
    emailjs.init('<USER ID>');
    emailjs.send("<YOUR SERVICE ID>","<YOUR TEMPLATE ID>", 
       {name: "James", notes: "Check this out!"});
}

Comment: I also just found out that the userID can be passed into the emailjs.send() as a fourth parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use npm [emailjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs) package

Installing the package:

```js
npm install emailjs
```